# How can I transfer all of my balance into another member? Mongoose

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am making a command that it gives all of my balance into another member, so if I use a command like `?give <member> all` which is I need to find out,

```
if(args[1] === "all") {
        const member = await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]) || message.mentions.members.first()
        const data = await economy.findOne({
            guildID: message.guild.id,
        })

        if(!data) return message.reply(`You don't have any records yet.`)
        if(0 === data.wallet) return message.reply(`You don't have enough balance, your current balance is $${data.wallet.toLocaleString()}`)

        economy.findOne({
            guildID: message.guild.id,
            userID: member.id,
        }, async(err, data) => {
            data.wallet += data.wallet
            data.save();
        })

        economy.findOne({
            guildID: message.guild.id,
            userID: message.author.id
        }, async(err, data) => {
            if(data) {
                const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setDescription(`You have successfully given ${member.user.username} amount of $${data.wallet.toLocaleString()}`)
                .setColor('RANDOM')
                .setTimestamp()
                message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})

                data.wallet -= data.wallet
                data.save()
            }
        })
```

Here's what I tried so far.

This is the part that going to transfer my balance to another user:

```
    economy.findOne({
        guildID: message.guild.id,
        userID: member.id,
    }, async(err, data) => {
        data.wallet += data.wallet
        data.save();
    })
```

The thing is its not working, since its all targeting the `member`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you used the variable `data` for both the original user and the "targeted" user. For instance, in your second code block, instead of adding the original user's balance to `data`, you are adding `data` (of the target user) to `data`; basically, you are doubling the target user's data.

Try renaming your `data` variables to something like

```js
    economy.findOne({
        guildID: message.guild.id,
        userID: member.id,
    }, async(err, other) => {
        other.wallet += data.wallet;
        other.save();
    })
```